# How use formData.append for a array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i want to send a form to my endpoint Profile, my problem is in the field user:{}, because i can't find the way to put my array into this field.

this are the field in my endpoint:

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "ci": "123456",
  "photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/profiles/12809632_10208569440535095_617453747387788113_n_zAUAVMf.jpg",
  "phone_number": "+59177621589",
  "user": {
    "id": 5,
    "username": "sdanderson",
    "first_name": "ssss",
    "last_name": "ssss"
  },
  "experience": "null",
  "typeskill": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "skill_name": "developer"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my service for make a PUT request:

```
putProfile(id:string,token:string,body:any,files:any):Observable<Profile>{

//save data to send to the endpoint for update
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    for (let file of files) {
        formData.append('photo', file);
    }
    formData.append('ci',body['ci']);  
    formData.append('phone_number', body['phone_number']); 
    formData.append('experience',body['experience']);
    formData.append('user',body['user']);//here i have inside the fields: body['user'].id,body['user'].first_name,body['user'].last_name





    //include header
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append("Authorization","Token "+ token);

    return this.http.put(this.api+"profile/"+id+'/',formData,{headers})
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 18):

FormData's *append()* method can only accept objects of **string** or **blob** type. If you need to append the array, use **JSON.stringify()** method to convert your array into a valid JSON string.

Here is how:

```
formData.append('user', JSON.stringify(body['user']));
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) you can read more about JavaScript's JSON object.

Comment: Tbh, it feels like a workaround, it's kind of stupid, that you have to stringify your data because of typescript.

Comment: I don't understand why 'body[]' is there?  What does it do?  is it necessary?

Answer (score 7):

> try like this.. it works in my project

```
 var formData= new FormData();

    for (let file of files) {
        formData.append('photo[]', file);
    }
```

Comment: file is a blob so that works with no issue b/c append() accepts string or Blob as a value.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and I declared an array in key. For your example it would look like this:

```
formData.append('user[id]', body['user']['id']);
...
```

It can be useful if you don't want to or can't parse JSON on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add four images to same formdata id. Below is my code

```
const files = event.target.files;
  for(var i=0;i< files.length;i++){
    this.formData.append("imgs",files[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do similar using angular frontend and spring backend. There was already a formData with file being sent and requirement was to send my array to backend, to the same endpoint for transaction rollbacks.

Edit: Another option and probably better option would have been to do [sprint-boot-multipart-requests](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests)

```
putProfile(id:string,token:string,body:any,files:any):Observable<Profile>{

    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    for (let file of files) {
        formData.append('photo', file);
    }
   ...
    
    let json = JSON.stringify(body['user']);
    formData.append('jsonUserArray',json);
    
    //service call  
    ...
}

//backend spring boot

@PostMapping("/profile/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProfile(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                                           @RequestParam(required=false) String jsonUserArray,
                                           @RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile file,
                                           @NotNull(message = "Authentication error.") Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    boolean accept = accept.equals("true") ? true: false;
    //convert the json to list of Users
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<User> listUsers = mapper.readValue(jsonUserArray, new TypeReference<List<Users>>(){});
    ...
    //service call  
}
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34471549)

Comment: Why not? Question was how "to send a form to my endpoint" and I gave solution to convert array to json and append to formData as string. The solution was already given and I added more details in angular so it is helpful to others.

Comment: It adds little to existing answers, and is answering a very old post.