# How am I supposed to append a Blob/File array to formData in typescript?

Tags: typescript, file, blob

This would work fine if I didn't have an ARRAY of files. But it needs to be an Array.

```
  let file1 = new File([""], "filename");
  let file2 = new File([""], "filename");
  let files = [file1, file2];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('files', files);
```

This works just fine in javascript. In typescript I get this error.

`TS2345: Argument of type 'Blob[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.   Type 'Blob[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Is there anything I can do besides // @ts-ignore?

Also the rest api I am working with requires the formData to be a Blob/File Array so I can't change anything there.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee No, this example only has one file but my problem is that FormData wants a Blob or String but not an Array of Blobs.

Comment: Try `formData.append('files', files as unknown as Blob);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to do something like this:

```
let file1 = new File([""], "filename");
let file2 = new File([""], "filename");
let files = [file1, file2];
let formData = new FormData();
for (let file of files){
    formData.append('files', file);
}
```

Will you let me know if that works?

The reason i think that is based on the discussion here: [How use formData.append for a array in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991758/how-use-formdata-append-for-a-array-in-typescript)