# Angular 10 | Http post | String array append FormData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, post

I have to make a post request to an api endpoint, but I get an error status 500.

```
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 500
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
```

This is my code:

```
var selectedIds = ["31"];
let sendData = new FormData();
sendData.append('auth', this.dataService.REG_AUTH);
sendData.append('identifier', identifier);
sendData.append('selected[]', selectedIds); 

this.http.post<any>('APIENDPOINT', sendData).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, error => {  
  console.log(error);
});
```

The issue is in this line: `sendData.append('selected[]', selectedIds);` I have no clue how to pass an array to FormData.

This is a working example from our android app. I need to convert this request in angular/typescript syntax:

```
@JvmSuppressWildcards
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("APIENDPOINT")
fun addData(
    @Field("auth") auth: String,
    @Field("identifier") identifier: String,
    @Field("selected[]") selected: ArrayList<String>
): Call<ResponseBody>
```

What I know so far:

It seems angular does not serialize the data, so I tried some hardcoded fixes, but none of these worked:

```
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', '%2231%22'); 
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', '31');
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', 31);
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', '%5B%2231%22%5D'); 
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', selectedIds); 
sendData.append('selected%5B%5D', JSON.stringify(selectedIds));
```

If I use `selected` instead of `selected[]`, then I get no error, but obviously no data is updated, so I am pretty sure it is a serialization/parsing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47103757/3486691):

> FormData's append() method can only accept objects of string or blob
> type. If you need to append the array, use JSON.stringify() method to
> convert your array into a valid JSON string.

```
formData.append('selected[]', JSON.stringify(selectedIds));
```

Comment: I see: `selected[]:  ["31"]`

Comment: can you please check the other form data values as well? This is quite strange. What happens if you only append that single value?

Comment: The issue was indeed somewhere else. Eventhough the var was there, it was the wrong var. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

The `statusCode 500` is the Internal Server Error, and it's the server-side problem. So, It's better to check the `API` if it can receive your request or not.

FormData's `append()` method accept `string` or `blob` type So you can use `JSON.stringify()` method (`formData.append('selectedIds', JSON.stringify(selectedIds));`). So try this:

```js
let selectedIds = ["31"];
let sendData = new FormData();
sendData.append('auth', this.dataService.REG_AUTH);
sendData.append('identifier', identifier);
sendData.append('selectedIds', JSON.stringify(selectedIds)); 

this.http.post<any>('APIENDPOINT', sendData).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
}, error => {  
  console.log(error);
});
```