# Why is FormData.set turning my array into a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a field that has multi-select enabled.
I'm able to get the form data and see the array containing all the files that were selected via the file field.

I'm trying to replace the file array with my selected_files array that I have modified, but when I use FormData.set, it is setting my array as a string it looks like.  Please see the below example.

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("asset-create-form"));
var files = form.getAll('file')
// file field has multiselect enabled so enduser can select more than one file
console.log(files)
>> [File, File, File, File, File] (5)
console.log(selected_files)
>> [File, File, File, File, File] (5)
form.set('file', selected_files)
new_files = form.getAll('file')
console.log(new_files)
>> ["[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File],[object File]"] (1)
```

Why is this a string?  How can I set my selected_files array to the file field?

If the set function can only set to a variable, then is there a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How use formData.append for a array in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991758/how-use-formdata-append-for-a-array-in-typescript)

Comment: Is your question answered?  If not, please comment accordingly. If yes, please pick an answer. If it was helpful, consider an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the sent value is different than `String` or `Blob` it will be automatically converted to `String`.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set#example

The `array` you're trying to `set` is neither `String` nor `Blob`, so it it converted.

In other words: The only values FormData can hold is `String` (any regular form field) and `Blob` (`input type=file`), meaning form data cannot hold other data types such as arrays, numbers, booleans, null, objects etc.

As for your second question, simply use [`FormData.prototype.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) in a loop:

```js
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById("asset-create-form"));
form.delete('file'); // delete the files already in the form data
selected_files.forEach(file => form.append('file', file));
```

Comment: but then why does console.log(files) return an array with all the selected files in it

Comment: Consider reading the basic documentation before asking on StackOverflow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll#returns *[getAll] Returns an array of [`FormDataEntryValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormDataEntryValue) whose key matches the value passed in the name parameter.*

Comment: Where is `selectedFiles` retrieved from? How does it relate to `files`?

Comment: selectedFiles is an array structured the same as the files array

Comment: Any you want to fully replace whatever form data with key `file` is already there?

Comment: there is some js functionality that allows a user to remove certain files from the list which will then remove that element from the selectedFiles array with the end goal being Posting FormData with selectedFiles instead of Files